# Python Wand: how to get the text bolded?

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library, wand

How to generate bolded text using python wand library? I cant get it to work.

http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/drawing.html - regarding documentation styles that are supported: 
    'undefined;
    'normal'
    'italic'
    'oblique'
    'any'
 there is no bold style?

sample usage i wanted to do a footer with a date that I get from contents file:

```
        with Image(width=150, height=25,) as img:
            draw.font_family = 'MS Reference Sans Serif'
            draw.font_size = 14.0
            draw.push()
            draw.font_style = 'italics'
            metrics = draw.get_font_metrics(img, contents['date'], multiline=False)
            draw.text(int((img.width - metrics.text_width)/2), int((metrics.text_height)), contents['date'])
            draw.pop()
            draw(img)
            img.save(filename='./temp/footer.png')
```

Maybe there is some way to make it bold in some quick way? Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

"bold" is not a `font_style`, it's a `font_weight`: http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/drawing.html#wand.drawing.Drawing.font_weight

And the integer values it takes are the values fonts typically use, where 400 is "normal" and 700 is "bold". (These are also used in CSS. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Common_weight_name_mapping.)

Answer (score 0):

Although mercator offered a correct answer to the title question, this answer focusing on the nested question:

> Maybe there is some way to make it bold in some quick way?

Try using the bold variant typeface directly.

Either specific the bold-font file provided by Microsoft ...

```
draw.font = 'refsanb.ttf`
```

... or use the font style with a "Bold" suffix.

```
draw.font_family = 'MS Reference Sans Serif Bold'
```